# Update only latest data from yfinance with pandas and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, yfinance

I've an old cvs file with this Yahoo Finance data named 'AAPL.csv'

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-25 | 174.19 | 176.97 | 174.14 | 176.08 | 46172700 |
| 2023-09-26 | 174.82 | 175.19 | 171.66 | 171.96 | 64588900 |
| 2023-09-27 | 172.61 | 173.03 | 169.05 | 170.42 | 66921800 |
| 2023-09-28 | 169.33 | 172.02 | 167.61 | 170.69 | 56294400 |
| 2023-09-29 | 172.02 | 173.07 | 170.33 | 171.21 | 51814200 |

I need to check today date with latest row date and update the latest days data and save in the same file. I've this code but have some problems with date format and not runs ok.

```
import os
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime

read_data = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
read_last_date_df = str(read_data['Date'].values[-1])
last_date_df = dateutil.parser.isoparse(read_last_date_df)

today = datetime.today()
dif_day_dates = int(today.strftime('%d')) - int(last_date_df.strftime('%d'))

if dif_day_dates > 0:
   update_data = yf.download(symbol, start=datetime.today() - last_date_df, end=datetime.today(), interval=timeframes_codedata['daily'])
   read_data[len(read_data)] = update_data
   read_data.to_csv('AAPL.csv')
```

Now i've this error:
if dif_day_dates > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'

Any suggestion or idea to solve this problem and apply this function in my app? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if dif_day_dates > 0:` is correct. The problem is:

```
update_data = yf.download(symbol, start=datetime.today() - last_date_df,
end=datetime.today(), interval=timeframes_codedata['daily'])
```

Let's look:

```
start = datetime.today() - last_date_df
print(start)
print(type(start))
'''
(datetime.timedelta(days=6, seconds=54260, microseconds=767898),)
<class 'tuple'>
'''
```

According to [**`documentation`**](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/main/yfinance/multi.py) `start` param takes a string expression and must be in `(YYYY-MM-DD)` format.

```
def download(tickers, start=None, end=None, actions=False, threads=True, ignore_tz=None,
             group_by='column', auto_adjust=False, back_adjust=False, repair=False, keepna=False,
             progress=True, period="max", show_errors=None, interval="1d", prepost=False,
             proxy=None, rounding=False, timeout=10, session=None):
    """Download yahoo tickers
    :Parameters:
        tickers : str, list
            List of tickers to download
        period : str
            Valid periods: 1d,5d,1mo,3mo,6mo,1y,2y,5y,10y,ytd,max
            Either Use period parameter or use start and end
        interval : str
            Valid intervals: 1m,2m,5m,15m,30m,60m,90m,1h,1d,5d,1wk,1mo,3mo
            Intraday data cannot extend last 60 days
        start: str
            Download start date string (YYYY-MM-DD) or _datetime, inclusive.
            Default is 99 years ago
            E.g. for start="2020-01-01", the first data point will be on "2020-01-01"
        end: str
            Download end date string (YYYY-MM-DD) or _datetime, exclusive.
            Default is now
            E.g. for end="2023-01-01", the last data point will be on "2022-12-31"
```

To avoid this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
start = (last_date_df +  timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now you can use these two values ​​in the **`yf.dowloand()`** function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can calculate this different format dates? I did test all my knowledge.

Comment: You're welcome! I added the possible solution at the end of my answer.

Comment: Super Thanks! Works fine!! Now I've wrong data when concatenate 2 dataframes. Pandas add a new first column as index in old rows. I'm trying to solve searching other stack questions. Any suggestion it is apprecied!

Comment: You can use `read_data = pd.concat([read_data,update_data])` then `read_data.to_csv('AAPL.csv')`.  This adds new data to the main df.

Comment: Yes, now I'm using this sentence but add new column to old rows as index like this:
,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
10788,2023-09-8,169.33999633789062,172.02999877929688,167.6199951171875,170.69000244140625,170.69000244140625,56294400
10789,2023-09-29,172.02000427246094,173.07000732421875,170.33999633789062,171.2100067138672,171.2100067138672,51814200
2023-10-02 00:00:00,,171.22000122070312,174.3000030517578,170.92999267578125,173.75,173.75,52164500
2023-10-03 00:00:00,,172.25999450683594,173.6300048828125,170.82000732421875,172.39999389648438,172.39999389648438,49594600

Comment: Please use `print(update_data.to_dict('list'))`  and  `print(read_data.to_dict('list'))` 
 then write output to the question.

Comment: Can't print your sentence, add this URLs with csv files.
Old data: https://giosolutionsgroup.com/AAPL.csv
Updated data: https://giosolutionsgroup.com/AAPL2.csv

Comment: I think read_data's index is the date column. Use first this `data=data.reset_index()`. Then use `read_data = pd.concat([read_data,update_data])`

Comment: Yes my index can be Date column (first column) With this reset adds 2 index column like "10789,10789.0,2023-09-29"

Comment: This is so weird. If you are using concat, both df's must have the same columns. You must ensure this. According to the csvs you sent, there is no error.

Comment: Those files are differents, AAPL.csv is an old file update to 2023-09-29 and AAPL2.csv is update to 2023-10-03. The last 3 rows in AAPL2.csv have correct data, but all old rows was added a new index column.

Comment: In this URL can you view my dataframe results https://giosolutionsgroup.com/delete.png

Comment: The problem is column names. Both dataframes must have the same columns. You should check column names. If not match you can use `rename` function. Secondly, check index names. The date column can be index column in first or second dataframe. I wrote the soluiton,  according to linked csvs you provided.

Comment: With reset index not runs, I set index for old DF 'read_data = read_data.set_index('Date')' and runs ok, but not all fine. It is curious, I've correct data in DFs but when makes concatenate add hour data to new rows, can you view in this file https://giosolutionsgroup.com/delete2.png

Comment: Okey. If you want to remove hours can you try this: `df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],format='mixed')`

Comment: Thanks for your help friend! All solved!