# Download historical beta data in python

Tags: python, dataframe, finance, yahoo-finance, yfinance

Beta values are calculated in yahoo finance and beta chart can be seen under stock chart.
However, i'm only able to download beta data for today and not the whole historical data with this code i copied from another post.

```
# import yfinance
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

# initialise with a df with the columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock','Beta'])

# here, symbol_sgx is the list of symbols (tickers) you would like to retrieve data of

# for instance, to retrieve information for DBS, UOB, and Singtel, use the following:
symbol_sgx = ['D05.SI', 'U11.SI','Z74.SI']
 
for stock in symbol_sgx:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(stock)
    info = ticker.info
    beta = info.get('beta')
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Stock':stock,'Beta':[beta]})
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], ignore_index=True)

# this line allows you to check that you retrieved the right information        
df
```

Is it possible? do i have to use a different API?

Comment: Check it this answer. It may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77236772/15415267